# list groups not working when specifying a userKey

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I try to receive all groups of a user. For that I want to use the list user endpoint:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/list

It works fine, unless I specify the userKey. In that case I get

```
{ [Error: Bad Request]
  code: 400,
  errors:
   [ { domain: 'global',
       reason: 'badRequest',
       message: 'Bad Request' } ] }
```

I am using the google-api package for node.js. I tried `primaryEmail` and `id` for `userKey`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. You cannot use the `customer` field and the `userKey` field at the same time.

Removing the `customer` field fixed the problem.